# Auto-close PPT using Macro in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to close my power point presentation while opening the PPT file after certain expiry time/dates. We need it in VBA using Macros.

Below code we are trying to do above requirements.

```
/////////////////////// 
Sub Auto_Open() 
ExpirationCode 
End Sub 
Sub ExpirationCode() 
Dim ExpirationDate As Date 
ExpirationDate = DateSerial(2011, 5, 8) 
MsgBox "Check1" 
If Now() >= ExpirationDate 
Then
Application.Windows(1).Close 
MsgBox "Check2" 
End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerPoint never runs code automatically when opening a presentation.

Code in Sub Auto_Open only runs when it's part of an add-in and the add-in loads.

It appears that you want to close the presentation if the current date is past an expiration date that you've set. If so, you might have to approach this differently.  For example, you could requre that the user install a small add-in in order to use your presentation.

The add-in would trap the event that occurs when PPT opens a presentation, check for some feature that identifies the presentation as yours and if so, would check for the expiration date and if it's past due, close the presentation.

Personally, I'd use tags.  Most users aren't aware of them, there's no UI for viewing/editing them.  Your event handler could be along the lines of:

```
With ActivePresentation
  ' Does it have an EXPIRE tag?  
  If Len(.Tags("EXPIRE")) > 0 Then
    ' It does, so it's one of yours.  Now get the date:
    If .Tags("EXPIRE") ... Then ' meets some condition you set
        .Close ' the presentation
        MsgBox "Expired!"
    End If
  End If
End With
```